# Projecto Netbeans com repositório git e Composer

Tags: php, git, netbeans, composer

Estou a desenvolver um projecto PHP que requer duas bibliotecas em separado. É me exigido que utilize o NETBEANS.

Para desenvolver os três em separado mas ao mesmo tempo e porque o projecto principal "*PROJECTO MAIN*" precisa dos outros dois, idealizei:

1. Todos os projectos com composer...como habitual
2. Todos os projectos com repositórios git... como habitual
3. Ao realizar alterações nos dois projectos complementares pretendo actualizar com o  composer o *projecto MAIN* logo após cada commit claro.

Para o fazer pensei que seria simples colocar no tal *PROJECTO MAIN* o seguinte:

```
"repositories": [ 
{   
   "packagist": false 
}, {    
 "type": "vcs",
 "url": "/localhost/htdocs/projecto1/" 
},{    
  "type": "vcs",
  "url": "/localhost/htdocs/projecto2/" 
}],
```

No entanto e por ser local não consigo que actualize directamente do repositório git de cada sub projecto criado pelo NETBEANS. Queria evitar colocar os projectos online enquanto não estiverem mais evoluídos. Tenho na raiz de cada projecto o respectivo ficheiro `composer.json` e claro o directório `.git` do repositório.

Após andar a bater a cabeça, resolvi perguntar se alguém já passou por uma situação igual e que me ilumine sobre este assunto...sff. Tenho bastante experiência com composer mas não estou mesmo a perceber por que é que não funciona.

ACTUALIZAÇÃO:
consigo como `artifact` colocando os repositórios em **zip's** mas está longe do que pretendia. Obriga-me a *zipar*, com o ficheiro `composer.json` na raiz do pacote zip...
exemplo:

```
 (...)
 "repositories": [
        {
            "packagist": false
        }, {
            "type": "artifact",
            "url": "/artifacts/"
        }],
 (...)
```

este excerto é colocado no `composer.json` do `projecto MAIN`. Dou a volta mas não consigo da forma como acho mais interessante e produtiva a partir de cada repositório `GIT` local para cada projecto dos quais o projecto principal depende.

Será que ninguém passou por isto ainda?

Comment: Você tem de executar um commit para atualizar dados no `git`. Uma ideia seria ter todos os três projétos em um único repositório no `git`.

Comment: @mutlei se ler bem a pergunta vera que no ponto 3 eu referi isso mesmo. Actualizo com commit... Mas não consigo chegar a ele. Quanto ao único repositório como sugere?

Comment: Um repositório somente com os três projétos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tenho andado e como mencionei na pergunta a desenvolver três projectos, onde um a que dei o nome de projecto MAIN depende de outros dois que são bases/componentes. Como o desenvolvimento é simultâneo a actualização do código no projecto principal sobre alterações nos dois projectos complementares é importante, portanto procurava uma solução prática dentro do editor que me foi imposto para o projecto ou seja o `NETBEANS`.

Como utilizo o `Composer` para gestão de pacotes e o `Git` como repositório teria de existir uma forma de realizar um commit em cada um dos projectos base e com o Composer no projecto MAIN referenciar os seus repositório "locais" e em desenvolvimento de forma a actualizar com as alterações realizadas.

A minha primeira solução foi com a abordagem de pacotes ZIP como apresentado na pergunta mas de facto obriga a zipar e a colocar o zip numa pasta de repositórios locais. Mas se realizo commits tinha de ser possível de actualizar o projecto MAIN a partir dos respectivos repositórios.

No `composer.jon` dos projectos base mantenho as configurações, mas no projecto MAIN a **novidade** acontece alterando:

```
(...)
 "repositories": [
        {
            "packagist": false
        }, {
            "type": "artifact",
            "url": "/artifacts/"
        }],
(...)
```

por:

```
(...)
"repositories": [
        {
            "packagist": false
        }{
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "projecto1",
                "version": "dev-master",
                "source": {
                    "url": "/localhost/htdocs/projecto1",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "origin/master"
                }
            }
        },{
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "projecto2",
                "version": "dev-master",
                "source": {
                    "url": "/localhost/htdocs/projecto2",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "origin/master"
                }
            }
        }],
(...)
```

Desta forma é possível realizar os commits nos dois projectos e no projecto MAIN com apenas um UPDATE do Composer actualizo o meu código para as últimas versões em desenvolvimento. Tratando-se de um editor "NETBEANS" são apenas simples cliques, *et voilá*. De referir que para conseguir esta solução é necessário ter o git instalado para apoio à linha comandos que o NETBEANS realiza!